# converting MySQL query to Codeigniter syntax

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have some problem converting a MYSQL query to CI syntax.

This my MySQL syntax:

```
select a.pbj_name as 'NAMA PERUSAHAAN', count(a.id_pbj) as 'JUMLAH PAKET', group_concat(c.paket_kode) as 'PILIHAN PAKET'
from jed_pbj a
left join jed_paket_pbj b
       on a.id_pbj=b.id_pbj
left join jed_paket c
       on b.id_paket=c.id_paket
group by a.id_pbj
```

Comment: hmm you dont have to convert it...codeigniter uses MySQL as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out this [Active Record](https://codeigniter.com/userguide2/database/active_record.html) class in Codeigniter,

```
$this->db->select("a.pbj_name as 'NAMA PERUSAHAAN', count(a.id_pbj) as 'JUMLAH PAKET', group_concat(c.paket_kode) as 'PILIHAN PAKET'");
$this->db->from('jed_pbj a');
$this->db->join('jed_paket_pbj b', 'a.id_pbj=b.id_pbj', 'left');
$this->db->join('jed_paket c', 'b.id_paket=c.id_paket', 'left');
$this->db->group_by("a.id_pbj"); 
$this->db->get();
```

Comment: Hai paulrajj thanks for your answer but query result still empty : 

object(CI_DB_mysql_result)#17 (7) { 
  ["conn_id"]=> <br/>
  resource(36) of type (mysql link persistent)
  ["result_id"]=>
  resource(46) of type (mysql result)
  ["result_array"]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["result_object"]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["current_row"]=>
  int(0)
  ["num_rows"]=>
  int(196)
  ["row_data"]=>
  NULL
}

Comment: @eric, you could use `$query = $this->db_get();`. Using the query values you can get the result array.  `$query->result_array()`. [Click here](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/results.html) to for generating query results in CI.